# What would be the Impact of increasing Workflow/Plugin WorkflowSettings.MaxDepth in CRM on premise instance?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am having dynamics CRM 8.2 on-premise instance and I want to increase WorkflowSettings.MaxDepth Property from max depth 8 to 120.
Could someone help me to identify, what will be the impact on my machine's RAM or CPU if I will increase it to 120?

Any help would much be appreciated.

Comment: What do you try to achieve by increasing the max depth? It sounds like you are trying to kill an ant with a butcher knife. If you want a scheduler, there are better solutions.

Comment: What will happen also depends on what is in your code. Do you have Thread.Sleep(<peroid>) in your code? If your workflow/plugin is sandboxed they are going to timeout in 2 minutes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible to say specifically.

The [depth limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg326836(v%3Dcrm.8)) is there is prevent infinite loops or processes that appear to be entering an infinitie loop. Increasing this setting means that long running processes are allowed to execute for longer. This is likely to make other processes less responsive as they wait for the long running process to complete.

Normally you shouldnt have to increase this setting.

> Used by the platform for infinite loop prevention. In most cases, this
>   property can be ignored.
>
> Every time a running plug-in or Workflow issues a message request to
>   the Web services that triggers another plug-in or Workflow to execute,
>   the Depth property of the execution context is increased. If the depth
>   property increments to its maximum value within the configured time
>   limit, the platform considers this behavior an infinite loop and
>   further plug-in or Workflow execution is aborted.
>
> The maximum depth (8) and time limit (one hour) are configurable by
>   the Microsoft Dynamics 365 administrator using the PowerShell command
>   Set-CrmSetting. The setting is WorkflowSettings.MaxDepth.

Answer (score 2):

The workflow system was never designed to run 120 cycles for a single process instance so I think it's safe to say that increasing it from 8 to 120 would constitute "abuse". If you were contemplating going from 8 to 12 it might be worth a discussion.

Since you're on-prem, if you want some additional run time for custom plugins and workflows you can register them outside the sandbox. However, best practice would be  to avoid abusing that too.

The supported way to do long running or deep operations is outside the system via an [Azure-aware plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/write-custom-azure-aware-plugin).